# How to add/remove a tag name for a file using URL structure (Mac OS X swift 3)

Tags: swift, url, tagname

I can read tag names like this:

```
let rv = try? someURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.tagNamesKey])
print(rv!.tagNames)
```

But how can I add or remove a tag name?

Thanks for your help,

Gilbert